# Bootstrap CDN not working

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, href, cdn

I am trying to embed bootstrap to an html file. I copied and pasted the links directly from their website and have also embedded the newest version of jQuery. The font styles seem to be correct, but the navbar and other classes are not working properly. Below is my code as well as a screenshot of the results.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
        
        <html lang="en">
        
        <head>
    
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
        <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">
    
          </head>
        
          <body>
        
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
              <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Navbar</a>
              <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
              </button>
        
              <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
                  <li class="nav-item active">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="#">Link</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                      Dropdown
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                      <div class="dropdown-divider"></div>
                      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
                <form class="form-inline my-2 my-lg-0">
                  <input class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
                  <button class="btn btn-outline-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit">Search</button>
                </form>
              </div>
            </nav>
        
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
           
            <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        
          </body>
        
        </html>
```

The navbar is one that I copied directly from bootstrap's documentation.

[image]

Also, as you can see, there are no errors in the console

Comment: Any errors in the console?  If you inspect the page and go to "Sources" can you see the css bootstrap file being included? Also check to make sure your console log is showing errors/warnings, as those might be hidden.

Comment: No. Sorry, I forgot to mention that

Comment: Include jQuery in the `<head>`.

Comment: Moving jQuery to the head gets the same results

Comment: @WaisKamal You can import scripts in body or head

Comment: I think I read it once in the jQuery documentation. They said include jQuery in the `<head>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have accidently copied a Bootstrap Theme instead of the actual bootstrap :)

Try using the CDN in https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_navbar&stacked=h. That seems to work fine.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
      </div>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Page 3</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="container">
    <h3>Basic Navbar Example</h3>
    <p>A navigation bar is a navigation header that is placed at the top of the page.</p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

or for just the `<head></head>` import

```html
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks. I just realized I may have accidently copied a theme rather than the actual bootstrap link.